# How to use the Firebase to send data to my PHP code

Tags: php, firebase, get

I am working with arduino project and I used PHP to connect to the Firebase.
I want to receive a data from firebase using PHP. I want the $new_ssid and $new_password to received from Firebase.
Here's my code:

```
<?php

require 'firebaseLib.php';
$Trash = $_GET["trash"];

$Distance = $_GET["distance"];
$Temperature = $_GET["temp_f"];
$Humidity= $_GET["humidity"];

$baseURI = 'x';
$token = 'x';

$devicestatus= array('Distance' => $Distance,'Temperature' => 
$Temperature,'Humidity' => $Humidity);

$firebasePath = '/x/';
$full= array($Trash => $devicestatus);

$fb = new Firebase($baseURI, $token);
$fb -> update($firebasePath, $full);

$new_ssid = "arduino";
$new_pass = "mechanical";
echo $new_ssid."/".$new_pass ;
?>
```

Comment: Using Curl you can send data to firebase

Comment: yes, I just want to receive data FROM firebase

Comment: Here is the complete doc : https://firebase-php.readthedocs.io/en/1.2.2/retrieving-data.html

Comment: thank you @BhAvikGajjar, but is it compatible with my code?

Comment: Okey........ :)

Comment: Hope this will be helpfull for ur solution : http://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-php/#/docs/cloud-firestore/master/firestore/firestoreclient

Comment: Thanks again, but I'm looking for something like gonna used a variable then use that to receive the data from firebase. Then add a function like this "$fb -> update($firebasePath, $full);" by instead using a GET.

Comment: I hope someone can give an appropriate solution for this, based on my code.

Comment: I still got no best result or solution for this, I need help guys :) thank you